# Mathematica-Netlogo Link Install Issue

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, netlogo

I have been trying to install the Netlogo-Mathematica Link to my Wolfram Desktop Version 12, using the NetLogo 6.1.0 package. It sometimes returns the directory not found error. If I try to load the package, it returns $Failed cannot open NetLogo. I'm on a macOS 10.14.5. Is it because I am on Wolfram Desktop rather than Mathematica, or is there some other problem?

Comment: Difficult to tell from this description. However, there are significant differences between NetLogo 5 and 6 and the extension does not say it works on v6. As a first attempt, you could try installing NetLogo v5.

Comment: There was a fix release for Mathematica Link after the release of NetLogo 6.1: https://github.com/NetLogo/Mathematica-Link/releases/tag/6.1.0  Make sure you've got that installed first.  I can only verify that I've gotten it to work on Mathematica 11 on macOS 10.14.5, not sure how Wolfram Desktop 12 would go.

Comment: @Jasper I got it to work! Thank you for your help.